# What is DataContext in XAML?

Tags: xaml

Please describe what is DataContext in XAML and when use it and relationship between {Binding} syntax. (with example) (In simple terms)

Thank you a lot.

Comment: This is why there's documentation and nifty things to help you find it like search engines amigo.

Comment: you can imagine data context is something that gets prepended with a dot to the property your write under that definition. if your data context is `Foo`, then you referenced `Bar` under it, then you are referencing `Foo.Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Data contexts are described within the Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A datacontext is data accessible to (aka within scope of) the current element. Thus a TextBox might have a datacontext set to SomeObject. If you where to bind to this using a binding, like this:

```
<TextBox DataContext={binding Path=SomeObject} Text={Binding Path=MyString} />
```

the textbox would have a datacontext containing the values in SomeObject. Any binding performed on this element (or any nested elements) will be within this scope. So, the binding on the 'text' dependency property would try to find the value in SomeObject.MyString.

It's important to note that the data context is passed down to its child elements: if a datacontext is set on a parent and you do not explicitly override this on its child elements, then the children will also have the same data context.